# Next JS 13 having to refresh to see css changes

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I recently updated to next 13. but now since I have I have to refresh the screen every time I make changes to my files.

Having to hard refresh every time I make changes

this is my next config

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
  experimental:{
    appDir: true
  }
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

I am using tailwind for my styling

Comment: Please see https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/43878.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem too.
To fix it you have to change all file names and directory names to lower case.
and you shouldn't set files name like this aaa-aaa.
if you imported files in uppercase you should fix them too.

Comment: This fixed my problem. So, I had imported the files as
`import ThemeToggler from "@/components/ThemeComponent";` and I had names my file as themeComponent.js.
After Updating the import hot reload was working :D yee!
`import ThemeToggler from "@/components/themeComponent";`